# Creating equally spaced quote & header

Tags: vertical-alignment

I want to create a heading for worksheets I will make. I want space for their name, the course, etc. in the upper leftmost space of the page (based on the page dimensions) and a TV/Movie quote in the upper rightmost space of the page.

To do this, I thought to use minipage to accomplish this as follows:

```
\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
\textbf{Name:} \makebox[3in]{\hrulefill} \\ 
\textbf{Course} \\ 
\textbf{Worksheet \#1} \\
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
{\em ``This is a quote that someone definitely said.'' } \\
\strut\hfill --H.P. Blabbermouth, That One Show You Know
\end{minipage}
```

[image]

At first glance, this works. But when you add more to the upperleft material or when the quote is longer, they offset each other so that they are no longer in the uppermost corners (like in the image below). Is there a way of making sure they always appear in the top left/right corner of the page?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `[t]`op-aligned `minipage`s to ensure that they are always aligned appropriately:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\textwidth}
  \textbf{Name:} \hrulefill ~~ \par
  \textbf{Course} \par
  \textbf{Worksheet \#1}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
  \raggedright
  {\itshape ``This is a quote that someone definitely said.''} \par
  \raggedleft
  --H.P.\ Blabbermouth, That One Show You Know
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I use minipage so often in the case where I put it is where I want it that I leave out the float options---so often I'd forgotten it had them. Thank you for the simple solution!

Comment: @TinyTim: They aren't floating specifications, but anchor points.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a tabular for this, but also to define a macro for such a repetitive task, which ensures the output will always be uniform.

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\worksheetheader}[3]{%
  % #1 = title of worksheet
  % #2 = quote
  % #3 = attribution
  \par\noindent
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
    @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
    >{\raggedright}p{0.58\textwidth}
    >{\raggedright}p{0.38\textwidth}
    @{}
  }
  \bfseries
  Name: \hrulefill\\
  Course\\
  Worksheet #1
  &
  \emph{\makebox[0pt][r]{``}\ignorespaces#2\unskip''}\\
  \raggedleft--- \ignorespaces#3\unskip\\
  \end{tabular*}\par
}

\begin{document}

\worksheetheader{\#1}{
  This is a quote that someone definitely said.
}{
  H.P. Blabbermouth, That One Show You Know
}

\bigskip

\worksheetheader{\#2}{
  This is a quote that someone definitely said.
  This is a quote that someone definitely said.
  This is a quote that someone definitely said.
  This is a quote that someone definitely said.
  This is a quote that someone definitely said.
  This is a quote that someone definitely said.
}{
  H.P. Blabbermouth, That One Show You Know
}

\end{document}
```

[image]